# How to trigger multiple Oozie coordinators with a different schedule by sharing the common job.properties

Tags: oozie, oozie-coordinator, oozie-workflow

I have a problem where i need to submit multiple coordinators(around 10) each with a different schedule and there is no dependency b/w each (ex: one for every 2 hrs ,12 hrs etc). I saw there is a limitation that we should have coordinator named as exactly coordinator.xml without a prefix or suffix (so that i can't differentiate). I don't want to have my code copied 10 times(maintaining folder for each coordinator) to handle this.  [sample folder with multiple coordinators](https://i.stack.imgur.com/unjaR.png)

Did any one have similar use-case; It would be really helpful if you share your thoughts on this Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can inject a variable

```
<coordinator-app name="my_app" frequency="${my_frequency}"  ...
```

Then run oozie with `-Dmy_frequency="* * * * 12"` for instance